# DartPad keeps saying expecting 2, receiving 3 arguments in constructor

Tags: dart

```
Email( List<String> to, String from, {String subject:null, String message:null, DateTime datetime:null, HashMap<String, List<String>> meta:null, List<Attachment> attachments:null})
```

get this error:

```
Uncaught NoSuchMethodError: incorrect number of arguments passed to method named ''
Receiver: ""
Tried calling: (Instance of 'JSArray<String>', "will@fallenreaper.com", Instance of '_HashMap<String, Object>')
Found: (to, from, subject, message, datetime, meta, attachments)
```

My class is:

```
class Email{
  Email( List<String> to, String from, {String subject:null, String message:null, DateTime datetime:null, HashMap<String, List<String>> meta:null, List<Attachment> attachments:null}){
    //do stuff.
  }
}
```

im trying to make it such that to and from are required, but the rest are optionally going to be passed in, in a map.  I thought i was doing this right, but it doesnt seem to be correct.

The DartPad is at:  https://dartpad.dartlang.org/4d32b88095a6509da511

Search for `TODO`

The Composer class is the part im implementing, leveraging the Email class i created.

Add some text to the Subject, and then click the "Send" button

Comment: Can you please add the link to your DartPad. DartPad has a share feature.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer there you go

Comment: it seems like some websites seem to be using the mapping for optional parameters by assigning the key as: `this.something` whereas i was thinking i could set the key to a variable i would then be able to check against, `{String something: "hello" }`  so that way there is a variable in that scope called: `something`

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer It seems that when i was looking at an example, I was passing in a `HashMap` into the 3rd argument spot whereas it is looking for explicit defintiions inline.   So, while i was saying:   `Email(to,from,map)`, I should actually say:   `Email(to, from, subject:map["subject"]);` which leads me to my follow on, would there be a way to pass in a map, possibly with the apply function, or is there really no way to do what i was thinking? maybe wrap it as a map instead?   {var map : null} and then say:  `Email(to,from, map:map);` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `Email` class' constructor

```
Email( List<String> to, String from, {String subject:null, String message:null, DateTime datetime:null, HashMap<String, List<String>> meta:null, List<Attachment> attachments:null}) { ... }
```

has 2 positional arguments and 5 optional named arguments.

You can simply pass positional parameters like you did in

```
new Email(map["to"], map["from"], map);
```

but optional names parameters need to be "named" like

```
new Email(map["to"], map["from"], subject: map);
```

If you want the optional parameters to be positional you need to change the constructor to

```
Email( List<String> to, String from, [String subject=null, String message=null, DateTime datetime=null, HashMap<String, List<String>> meta=null, List<Attachment> attachments=null]) { ... }
```

You can't have optional named *and* optional positional arguments at the same time. If you have a longer parameter list like in your `Email` constructor, named optional arguments are usually better because you can specify with a name which parameter the passed value should be assigned to and there is no need to pass `null`s or `''`s for parameters you want to skip.

Comment: what if i created an options variable like this constructor:   `Email (List<String> to, String from, [HashMap<String, Object> options = null]){...}` and that way, i create a map prior of options, instead of passing in a bunch of variables.  Then just read that Map for particular keys and process accordingly?

Comment: Like the following: `Email( List<String> to, String from, [HashMap<String, Object> options = null])   {
    this._to = to;
    this._from = from; 
    if (options == null) return;
    
    this._subject = options.containsKey("subject")?options["subject"]:null;
    this._message = options.containsKey("message")?options["message"]:null;
    this._metadata = options.containsKey("meta")?options["meta"]:null;
    this._datetime = options.containsKey("datetime")?options["datetime"]:new DateTime.now();
    this._attachments = options.containsKey("attachments")?options["attachments"]:null;
  }`

Comment: You can do that of course. `Map` would probably be better than `HashMap`. I don't see a necessity to specify a concrete map implementation. I would prefer an `EmailOptions` class because I assume the set of supported options is fixed. This would provide proper auto-completion, analyzer type-checking and simpler syntax for the user of the `Email` class.

Comment: true, just abstract that to another class for proper processing instead of doing it inside the `Email` class.  I actually like that.  I think I will go this route instead.... with the Options map.  that way, the existing map can be passed in and would just need to adjust reference from `subject` to `options["subject"]`